# Use Arris TG1682G cable gateway as Wi-Fi router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem

I have a Comcast Arris TG1682G cable gateway which I am not using for my cable connection. It has good 2.4 and 5GHz Wi-Fi coverage, and I was hoping to find a way to use it as an AP to broadcast Wi-Fi when connected to my current modem, a Zoom 5370.

Of course, it is not meant for this, and it doesn't have a[n Ethernet] WAN port. I looked around in its configuration pages, and I attempted to find an answer online, but pretty much everything online referenced the opposite: turning off the Wi-Fi of the device and passing that off to a different router.

I have not been able to get this to work at all. Is there some way to trick the device into acting as a regular Wi-Fi router?

Comment: You called it a cable modem, but in DOCSIS terms it's really a cable gateway, not just a modem. So while we're getting terminology straight, is your current modem truly just a modem or is it a gateway as well? If you're not sure, please post the make and model of your current "modem". Whether or not your current DOCSIS device is just a modem makes a difference for how to answer your main question.

Comment: Give it a unique static IP in the same subnet, disable DHCP and connect a lan port to router/switch. If you can't do either of those things or it doesn't work, it's probably hard-coded to only use the cable internet.

Comment: @Spiff my current device is the Zoom 5370. When I did some basic research before, I understood a gateway to be a combined modem and Wi-Fi router, but I could be wrong? In any case, I just used the term modem because on the box, the big title text said "Cable Modem." It has essentially no options in its configuration menu.

Comment: @acejavelin There is no way to disable DHCP on the Arris gateway. I can make the DCHP range a single address, but that didn't help. I think the firmware might be designed to only allow it to use the cable internet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your new modem is truly just a modem, so if you want to share that connection to more than one device, you’ll need something to act as a NAT gateway router between your cable modem and the rest of your network. So you definitely need something with an Ethernet WAN port. Since your Arris TG1682G only has a DOCSIS WAN port, it won’t work for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for clearly explaining this. I hadn't thought about what device would be supplying NAT for the network.